# Hadoop hdfs: input/output error when creating user folder

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've followed the instructions in [Hadoop the definitive guide, 4th edition : Appendix A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491901632) to configure Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode. Everything is working good, except for when I try to make a directory :

`hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/$USER`

The commande is returning the following message : `mkdir: /user/my_user_name': Input/output error`.

Although, when I first log into my root account `sudo -s` and then type the `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/$USER` commande, the directory `'user/root'`is created (all directories in the path).

I think I'm having Hadoop permission issues.

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if underlying filesystem has any IO error?

Comment: The command `mkdir -p user/$USER` works fine (I'm creating the hierarchy in my home directory, no need to root), I assume that the filesystem has not IO error

Comment: You need to be the HDFS superuser to make those folders. Apparently, yours is `root`, but that's not always the case

Comment: Which Hadoop version are you using?

Comment: I got the same error message, once I tried access the file system and if forgot to configure fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml (see also: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

Comment: use sudo before the command

Answer (score 3):

It means that you have a mistake in the 'core-site.xml' file. For instance, I had an error in the first line (name) in which I wrote 'fa.defaultFS' instead 'fs.defaultFS'.

After that, you have to execute the script 'stop-all.sh' to stop Hadoop. Probably, here, you will have to format the namenode with the commands: 'rm -Rf /app/tmp/your-username/*' and 'hdfs namenode -format'. Next, you have to start Hadoop with the 'start-all.sh' script.

Maybe, you have to reboot the system when you have executed the stop script.

After these steps, I could run that command again.

Answer (score 0):

I Corrected the core-site.xml file based on standard commands and it works fine now.

```
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/your_user_name/hadooptmpdata</value>
        <description>Where Hadoop will place all of its working files</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
        <description>Where HDFS NameNode can be found on the network</description>
</prosperty>
```